# Furnace blower works when turned ON from thermostat. Furnace does not start when Fan is on Auto mode - gives blower communication error

Tags: central-heating, blower

My heating (Forced Air/Gas) stopped working and I noticed B5 error code on board - "Blower motor locked rotor". After replacing the blower motor (ECM motor), I am getting B1 code - "Blower communication error". Furnace is trying to start but immediately gives communication error before flame/heat comes on. However, if I switch fan to auto mode, using thermostat, then furnace works and blows hot air. What could be the reason if prior to motor change it was communicating and giving B5 error and after motor replacement it cannot communicate? Is the problem in board, or wiring?
Model: GMVC80704BXAB

Comment: What make is that furnace of yours? (i.e. who manufactured it?)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  If you google the model number you'll find it's a Goodman.

Comment: @SteveWellens -- I was suspecting it was a Goodman from the model number but wanted the OP to confirm that :)